# Multiplying two different dataframes only for completely matching row and column names

Tags: r, loops, match

Lets make a dummy data first

```
a=data.frame(average=c(5,6), row.names=c("Q", "R"))
> a
  average
Q       5
R       6

b=data.frame(c(5,5,7), c(8,9,10), c(11,12,14))
> colnames(b)<-c("Q","QQ","R")
> b
  Q QQ  R
1 5  8 11
2 5  9 12
3 7 10 14
```

i want to multiply columns of 'b' that completely match with the row names of 'a' (here, Q and R completely match). But when I make a simple loop it gives

```
n = row.names(a)
> lapply(1:length(n), function(i)
+ a[grep(n[i], row.names(a)),]*b[,grep(n[i], colnames(b))])
[[1]]
   Q QQ
1 25 40
2 25 45
3 35 50

[[2]]
[1] 66 72 84
```

which means it also multiplies QQ since Q and QQ have one letter in common! How can I get the following?

```
[[1]]
[1] 25 25 35

[[2]]
[1] 66 72 84
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want column `"Q"` of a data.frame, you can just do `b[, "Q"]` or `b[["Q"]]`. Whereas doing `b[, grep("Q", colnames(b))]` will return all columns whose name contains a `Q`. With that in mind, your code should be:

```
n <- rownames(a)
lapply(1:length(n), function(i) a[n[i], ] * b[, n[i]])
```

or

```
lapply(rownames(a), function(i) a[i, ] * b[, i])
```

Maybe a more elegant approach would be to do:

```
i <- intersect(rownames(a), colnames(b))
Map(`*`, a[i, ], b[, i])
```